# Git push doesn't ask for password and gives 401. Fine when password typed inline in console

Tags: git, msysgit

I've tried googling and stack-googling for this, but haven't found the solution still. I'm working with Git under Windows.

When I try either of those commands:

```
$ git push origin master
$ git push https://name@server/git/repoName.git
```

i.e. without typing my password, each time I get the authentication error (it doesn't even ask for password):

```
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 401
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

When I provide my password directly (inline), push works fine:

```
$ git push https://name:myPasswordHere@server/git/repoName.git
```

Some additional info if required that I think might be useful:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://name@server/git/repoName.git (fetch)
origin  https://name@server/git/repoName.git (push)
```

Contents of .gitconfig: (`git config --list` actually displays it, so the file is read).

```
[http]
    sslVerify = false
[user]
    name = foo
    email = foo@foo.com
```

Full list of configuration options:

```
$ git config --list // outside the repo
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslverify=false
user.name=foo
user.email=foo@foo.com
```

Any hints what can be wrong?

Comment: What happens if you omit your username - eg `git push https://server/git/repoName.git`?

Comment: Exactly the same as with the username -- 401.

Comment: This feels like a server problem more than a usage problem, as I usually get prompted for a password when I don't specify one, be it to github or privately hosted git server. I would start investigating in that direction. Who is hosting the server you push to?

Comment: It is a company server. For all the other folks from the team it works normally and they seem to have very same config as me. I've investigated it with them and no one can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Works normally == asks for a password.

Comment: I guess I'll try to create a new repo in some other place on the disk and then try to push and see if this changes anything...

Comment: What's the output of `git --version`?

Comment: `git version 1.7.8.msysgit.0`

Comment: are you behind a proxy which needs authentication or is the server behind a reverse proxy or something ?

Comment: jakub.g did you ever solve this issue?  I am seeing something simliar and it looks to be linked to the version of git the client is running anything over git version 1.7.4.x looks to have this issue.

Comment: @AntonioDolcetta: Well, I'm behind The Big Company Firewall of course with respect to the Internet, but wrt to the Git server, IMO it's in the same local network. Locally I don't think there are any proxies.

Comment: @st3v3o: I moved to the other task for now, I'll come back to investigate the issue when I find some time (not a high priority temporarily for me). But it's good to know someone has the same issue ;)

Comment: I just updated the "server" to 1.7.9.2 and it looks like clients with a git version greater then 1.7.6 do not work now.

Comment: Actually 1.7.7.1 client is fine. I had the luck to install broken 1.7.8 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we are also having the same problem, the solution was to downgrade to 1.7.6 or similar, everything we tried with 1.7.8/9 failed in the same way

http://code.google.com/p/git-core/issues/detail?id=2

Comment: it's not a proper solution, but I had to downgrade too in ordere to make it works

Comment: I took my time to play, installing 3 last msysgit versions on my machine, on default settings. The results are: 1.7.7.1 is ok, 1.7.8 is broken, 1.7.9 is broken.

Comment: for future visitors: 1.7.11 is also broken. 1.7.7.1 remains the last good one in this respect.

Comment: have you found any reason why this would be? I tried looking again, but it's a deathly silence....nobody is talking about it and nobody seems to have any information on the topic...very puzzling cause I'm sure we're not the only ones having problems

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Git's http support has been very buggy (sometimes due to bugs in cURL, the http library used by Git).  If possible, use ssh instead.

A few guesses:

1. The `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable is set.
2. The `.netrc` (maybe `_netrc` on Windows?) file used by cURL contains a wrong password for your site.
3. There's a bug in Git or the cURL library.  Try updating to the latest version of [Git for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3&q=official+Git) or downgrading to the same version used by your coworkers.

Comment: Thankfully we run very little windows...so clients are running either on Ubuntu or OS X...and the server is running Centos.  I think it might be a bug in GIT, sense downgrading fixes the issue.